# Beginners AngularJS code not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and was just playing around with the stuff. Here is my HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="nameController">
    <input type="text"  value="Jack" ng-model="fname" />
    <input type="text" value="Sparrow" ng-model="lname" />
    {{getFullName()}}
</div>

<input type="text" value="Hello" />
```

And here is the controller code:

```
function nameController($scope) {
    $scope.getFullName = function () {
        return $scope.fname + " " + $scope.lname;
    };
}
```

I have set the value of the input text fields using the `value` attribute. So I expected the controller function `getFullName` to read those values and return the full name on page load. But what I get is:

```
undefined undefined
```

And the input text boxes empty. Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

If you want default values for those inputs, use the model and set them as properties on `$scope` in the controller:

```
function nameController($scope) {
    $scope.fname = "Jack";
    $scope.lname = "Sparrow";
    $scope.getFullName = function () {
        return $scope.fname + " " + $scope.lname;
    };
}
```

You can then remove the `value` attribute from the markup. This keeps the data nicely separated from the view. Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/YTG5Q/).

Alternatively, you could use the [`ngInit`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInit) directive:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="nameController" ng-init="fname = 'Jack'; lname = 'Sparrow'">
    <input type="text" ng-model="fname" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="lname" />
    {{getFullName()}}
</div>
```

Comment: ok dat works....but just to know why it doesn't pick up data from value attr of input element on page load

Comment: @iBlue - Just because that's the way it works. The data belongs in the model, not in the view.